# Getting the values undefined form string bulider in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

i am sending some values via post method to php page  in the jquery ajax method using string bulider in the server side coding.But when i try to send the values is says undefined.i dono how pass the cliendid.it is correct or not?

```
     protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        c.MyQuery("insert into tblHrims_currentOpeningsNew(nvrDesignation,nvrCompany,nvrExperience,nvrLocation,nvrEducation,nvrDepartment,nvrIndustryType,nvrFnalArea,nvrJobDesc,nvrDesiredProfile,nvrContactPerson," +
" nvrContactNumber,nvrEmailId,nvrWantedPositions,nvrAddedBy,dttAddedon) values('" + txtDesg.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + ddlCompany.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + txtExperience.Text + "','" + txtLocation.Text + "','" + txtEducation.Text + "'," +
" '" + txtDept.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + ddlIndustryType.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + ddlFnalArea.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + txtJobDesc.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + txtDesiredProfile.Text.Replace("'", "") + "'," +
" '" + txtContactName.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + txtContactno.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + txtEmailid.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + txtPositionWanted.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "'," +
" '" + txtAddedBy.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "") + "','" + c.GetValue("select getdate()") + "')");
        string strID = c.GetValue("select max(intsno) from tblhrims_currentopeningsNew");
        lblAlert.Visible = true;
        lblAlert.Text = "SucessFully Added";
        StringBuilder mystringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        mystringbuilder.Append("$(document).ready(function(){\n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var ddlCompany = $(\"#<%=this.ddlCompany.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtLocation = $(\"#<%=this.txtLocation.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtDept = $(\"#<%=this.txtDept.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var ddlIndustryType = $(\"#<%=this.ddlIndustryType.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtDesg = $(\"#<%=this.txtDesg.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var ddlFnalArea = $(\"#<%=this.ddlFnalArea.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtExperience = $(\"#<%=this.txtExperience.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtJobDesc = $(\"#<%=this.txtJobDesc.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtEducation = $(\"#<%=this.txtEducation.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtDesiredProfile = $(\"#<%=this.txtDesiredProfile.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtPositionWanted = $(\"#<%=this.txtPositionWanted.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtAddedBy = $(\"#<%=this.txtAddedBy.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtContactName = $(\"#<%=this.txtContactName.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtEmailid = $(\"#<%=this.txtEmailid.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        var txtContactno = $(\"#<%=this.txtContactno.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("            $.ajax({\n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("            type: \"POST\",\n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("             url: \"http://172.16.126.32/Riyas/marggroup.com/get-current-openings.php\",\n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("             data: \"ddlCompany=\" + ddlCompany + \"& txtLocation=\"+ txtLocation+\"& txtDept=\"+ txtDept+\"& ddlIndustryType=\"+ ddlIndustryType+\"& txtDesg=\"+ txtDesg+\"& ddlFnalArea=\" + ddlFnalArea+\"& txtExperience=\"+ txtExperience+\"& txtJobDesc=\"+ txtJobDesc+\"& txtEducation=\"+ txtEducation+\"& txtDesiredProfile=\"+ txtDesiredProfile+\"& txtPositionWanted=\"+ txtPositionWanted+\"& txtAddedBy=\"+ txtAddedBy+\"& txtContactName=\"+ txtContactName+\"& txtEmailid=\"+ txtEmailid+\"& txtContactno=\"+ txtContactno,\n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("             success: function(response){\n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("                $('div.success').html(response); \n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("            }\n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("        });\n");
        mystringbuilder.Append("});\n");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", mystringbuilder.ToString(), true);
    }
```

Comment: On what line is "undefined" - have you checked the browser's console (F12) ? What looks you javascript like in the HTML ?

Comment: see i wll send this testbox values to php....so these values i am getting as undefined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the client ids directly in the generated script rather than using a directive to load them.

For example, change the following line:

```
mystringbuilder.Append("        var ddlCompany = $(\"#<%=this.ddlCompany.ClientID %>\").attr('value'); \n");
```

to:

```
mystringbuilder.Append("        var ddlCompany = $("').Append(this.ddlCompany.ClientID).Append("').attr('value');").AppendLine();
```

Also, you should replace the `\n`s with AppendLine() as in the example above.

Comment: @competent_tech. I think you are missing the quotes around the ClientID in the jquery object. Should be: `mystringbuilder.Append("var ddlCompany = $('").Append(this.ddlCompany.ClientID).Append("').attr('value');").AppendLine();`

Comment: @DidierG. Thanks for the catch, it's late.

Comment: @user1113151: Sorry, there was one error in the code that I have corrected in the answer thanks to Didier G. However, you will have to change the rest of the lines that try to use clientid to use the same pattern. Also, I believe that that the \n may be causing javascript errors as well.